# how do I fix my suhosin.so error

Tags: php, mysql, security, suhosin

I'm (very) new to databases.  I've designing a site, and was happy that I got a handle on the errors in my error log.  Recently my error log keeps logging in "PHP Warning: ...unable to load...suhosin.so"

Obviously a new entry is made whenever I query something.  Unfortunately, google searches tell me 2 things: (1)the error isn't really a big thing (but I was proud that my error log stopped growing!) and (2) suhosin.so is an advanced topic (and security patch) for mysql.

The advanced part has me a bit freaked out as to how I can "fix" it...

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

It says `extension=suhosin.so` somewhere in your php.ini. You can either remove or comment out this line to disable the protection, or install the current suhosin extension from suhosin.org. Simply

```
grep -r suhosin.so /etc/php5
```

(The path may be different on your system.)

Suhosin is an advanced protection system for PHP. (not mysql)

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

(1) Install suhosin extension from `suhosin.org` if it's not installed yet

(2) Un-comment (by removing #) `extension=suhosin.so` from your php.ini file

(3) Restart your web-server (Apache?)

This should fix your suhosin.so error.